# Passing actual argument by function return value only has one copy temporary variable or two?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know when passing argument by value, compiler calls copy constructor, creates a temporary variable to store the copy value and uses it in function.

But I want to know if passing anonymous function return value will the compiler creates two temporary variables? For example,

```cpp
void func(Foo foo){..}

func(make_foo(args));
```

First the compiler creates a variable to store result of `make_foo(args)`, then it creates second variable, which is copy of first, to formal parameter of `func()`?

I did a small test by `make_shared`, from the result it seems only one temporary variable was created. But I don'y know whether the first variable has been released, like leaving its scope?

This is my test code:

```cpp
void test(std::shared_ptr<int> sp) {
  std::cout << sp.use_count() << std::endl;
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(10);
  auto sp2 = std::shared_ptr<int>(sp);
  std::cout << sp.use_count() << std::endl;
  test(std::shared_ptr<int>(sp));
  std::cout << sp.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

result is

```
2
3
2
```

Comment: C++17 forces some "optimization" in that regard.

Comment: It's called copy elision (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) or return value optimisation and it is safe to rely on it, because it is part of the C++ standard.

Comment: You could be seeing [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) or it could be using a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Comment: @RL-S You can only rely on it in C++17 and newer.  The Q is tagged with C++11

Comment: @NathanOliver good point

Comment: It's perhaps easier to follow what it's doing if you create your own class to track it instead of using `shared_ptr`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/a87Enf4Y5)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: And even with the extra temporary with and without `-fno-elide-constructors` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PhPPzjfd8).